# How to check if an url is an image with fetch in js?

Tags: javascript, image, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I have a problem with a code to check if url is an image.

Actually, I have this code:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result")
document.getElementById("someForm").addEventListener("submit",(event)=>{
  event.preventDefault()
  result.textContent = "Image Test"
  var img = document.createElement("img")
  img.setAttribute("src",imageUrl.value)
  img.addEventListener("load",(event)=>{
    result.textContent = "Image ok"
    setTimeout(()=>{
      result.textContent = "Waiting for imageUrl..."
    },2000)
  })
  img.addEventListener("error",(event)=>{
    result.textContent = "Link is not an image"
    setTimeout(()=>{
      result.textContent = "Waiting for imageUrl..."
    },2000)
  })
})
```

```css
input[type="url"] {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="someForm">
  <label for="imageUrl">Enter image url here:</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="url" id="imageUrl">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<p id="result">Waiting for imageUrl...</p>
```

But when I try it out with fetch or XMLhttprequest I got a error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

Do you know hot to do that with fetch?
Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine, can you share the URL you tried that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: you would need some kind of CORS proxy do fetch the actual data from a remote source. This is not something that can be solved solo with fetch or xmlhttprequest. this is a [CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) issue/restriction

Comment: Ok thanks to your responses
To precise that I want is to get any url that user can provide and then check if url exist and if the image format is one of the allowed format. My code works but I can't display progress bar, check header response or any advanced thinks like that. Actually, my page is on gh-pages